# What exactly is an "instrumentation radar"?

Tags: radar

I am coming across this term "instrumentation radar" without exactly defining it but with adjectives like high performance, mono pulse etc.  But what exactly is an instrumentation radar?

Answer (score 1):

An instrument is a gadget for measuring something. So an instrumentation radar is a radar for measuring something. Perhaps it is not the most helpful name.

[Here](http://www.globalsecurity.org/space/library/report/1998/260.pdf) is a document from 1998 that maps out the future of instrumentation radar for use in places like military missile ranges.

> Instrumentation radar has played a very significant role in testing and training for more than
>   50 years.  Along with optics, it has been a major supplier of time-space-position-information
>   (TSPI).  With the advent of the Global Positioning System (GPS), the need for instrumentation
>   radar for TSPI has been called into question.  Is radar still needed? Or can it be replaced by GPS?
>
> ...
>
> It is also needed for a
>   variety of specialized measurements, including radar cross section (i.e., stealthiness),
>   characterization of debris, and assessment of damage at intercept.

Comment: I think that we need to consider the term in comparison to a "navigation radar". In the latter case you mostly care about where you are relative to other objects / obstacles; but it is possible to use (stationary) radar specifically to measure distance, direction, and even sub-surface composition. I suspect that is where the distinction comes in. I agree with you it's not the most helpful term.

Comment: @Floris: Thanks for the clarification.  I know what is instrumentation but I was not able to relate it to radar as the very radar begins with the distance measurement concept and I was trying to get the exact way it is used in literature.  Now I got it.  It might have been loosely defined/used.